# command not found error when redirecting input

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I wrote a shell script to be ran on a text file (called test.txt). This script will read an input file, iterate over its lines, and do some action.

I first compile my program:

```
chmod +x ./cleanLines.txt
```

then run my command:

```
./cleanLines.txt < ./test.txt > output.txt
```

However, the error I get is:

```
./cleanLines.txt: line 7: [[: command not found
./cleanLines.txt: line 7: [[#Some: command not found
./cleanLines.txt: line 7: [[HelloWorld: command not found
./cleanLines.txt: line 7: [[Today: command not found
./cleanLines.txt: line 7: [[Cookie: command not found
./cleanLines.txt: line 7: [[: command not found
./cleanLines.txt: line 7: [[Out: command not found
./cleanLines.txt: line 7: [[: command not found
./cleanLines.txt: line 7: [[: command not found
```

My test.txt file is as follows:

```
*blank line*(Won't let me edit it like this here)
#Some note
HelloWorld #note
Today is sunny
Cookie Monster

Out of things to say
```

and cleanLines.txt is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

    PATH=${PATH[*]}:.
    #filename: clearLines

    while read line; do
        if [[$line != ""]]; then
                .
                .
                # Doing stuff
                .
                .
        fi
    done < test.txt
```

NOTE: line 7 is:

```
if [[$line != ""]]; then
```

What is the problem here? Unless I have to, (since we were strictly told NOT to) I prefer not to post the rest of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces are important.  Replace:

```
if [[$line != ""]]; then
```

with:

```
if [[ $line != "" ]]; then
```

#### Examples

Observe that these fail:

```
$ line=1 ; [[$line != "" ]] && echo yes
bash: [[1: command not found
$ line=1 ; [[ $line != ""]] && echo yes
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `yes'
```

But this version, with the correct spacing, succeeds:

```
$ line=1 ; [[ $line != "" ]] && echo yes
yes
```